# Transiting through Scotland from a quarantined country

Tags: covid-19

The Scottish government has just added Switzerland to its list of countries from which travellers from Saturday morning must enter 14 days of quarantine.

It just so happens someone is coming from Switzerland to stay at my house in England on Saturday evening.

The English list doesn't include Switzerland. However they will be entering the UK from Edinburgh Airport then taking the train down.

How does this affect the quarantine situation? Do they have to do it still as they entered in Scotland or since they're staying in England and neither Scotland or Switzerland are on England's bad list it's OK? They're thinking of cancelling thinking the rules mean they are a prisoner in Scotland for 14 days - this is absolutely not the case surely?

Comment: As an update.... nothing bad happened and apprently they were just waved through at the airport with the border official barely looking at their form that said they were staying in England/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Scottish advice](https://www.gov.scot/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-public-health-checks-at-borders/) on self-isolation states:

> You can only leave your accommodation in limited circumstances. These include where:
>
> - you need to travel to leave Scotland, provided that you do so directly

Which would suggest that your friend won't be required to spend the 14 days in Scotland - they are allowed to travel to leave Scotland (i.e. to travel to you in England) but must do so directly (you mentioned they were getting the train so might be worth reminding them about the face-covering requirements on public transport). Since neither Scotland nor Switzerland are on the English list they don't have isolate in England, assuming they haven't been in any other places in the previous 14 days that **do** trigger a quarantine of course.

On that point it's worth double checking their route since [this](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/switzerland/coronavirus) could affect them:

> If you use Basel-Mulhouse-Freiburg airport to return to the UK, you will transit France and therefore will be required to self-isolate on your return to the UK.